# RecyclerView items duplicate and constantly changing

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**What's Happening:**

The list `(RecyclerView)` is mixing up the data when I scroll.

> **I.E** when I scroll back up after scrolling down, some of the list items are repeated, not displaying proper content.

```
package jamesnguyen.newzyv2.UI_update;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import jamesnguyen.newzyv2.R;
import jamesnguyen.newzyv2.RSS_Processcors.RssItem;

public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.FeedViewHolder> {

    private static List<RssItem> items = null;
    private static Context context;

    public RVAdapter(Context context, List<RssItem> items) {
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public static List<RssItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public RVAdapter.FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        return new FeedViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter.FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FeedViewHolder.getTitle().setText(items.get(position).getTitle());
        FeedViewHolder.getPubDate().setText(items.get(position).getPubDate());
        //FeedViewHolder.getDescription().setText(items.get(position).getDescription());
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private static CardView cv;
        private static TextView title;
        private static TextView pubDate;
        private static TextView description;

        FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            pubDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.pubDate);
            //description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        }

        public static TextView getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public static TextView getPubDate() {
            return pubDate;
        }

        public static TextView getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

I believe maybe some works have to be done with the recycling process of RecyclerView but nothing i tried seesm to work.

Answer (score 94):

done .

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling except for reusing it for the same item, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.

Answer (score 45):

Only two things in your RecyclerView adapter

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

and in constructor of adapter

```
 setHasStableIds(true);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Careful using `setHasStableIds(true)`, it can have some unexpected behaviour

Answer (score 12):

The problem is the `CardView` and `TextView` objects are declared static inside the `FeedViewHolder`. That means that all the calls trying to set the title in the `onBindViewHolder` method hit the latest inflated View.

The fix is to remove the `static` from `cv`, `title`, `pubDate`, `description`, then implement some non static setters like:

```
public void setTitle(String s) {
    title.setText(s);
}
```

To be called in the `onBindViewHolder` method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RVAdapter.FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.setTitle(items.get(position).getTitle());
    //...
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. The views had to be initialized as objects of ViewHolder class and not the Adapter class. Then they had to be called from the reference of the holder object in onBindViewHolder

Comment: **This is the only correct answer on this question.** If you are experiencing this issue, **your adapter has a bug** and you need to find and fix it, rather than using hacks that cause collateral damage.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with a big grid recyclerview with hundreds of numbers that should have appeared sequentially but their order was getting mixed up and repeated.

```
// More concise code with Kotlin expressions
override fun getItemId(position: Int) = position.toLong()
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position
```

Added above lines to the adapter.

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling except for reusing it for the same item, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin with clearing the previous items from the LinearLayout list item from the RecyclerView

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(view: MyViewHolder, index: Int) {
        view.guideLinearLayout.removeAllViews()
/* do binding here*/
}

override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
       return position.toLong()
}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
       return position
}
```

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling except for reusing it for the same item, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody using kotlin, use like inside RecyclerView.Adapter

The setHasStableId(true) is to be applied to the adapter of RecylerView

```
 init {
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }
```

Override the position with product id

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return myList?.get(position).id
    }
```

Comment: `getItemId` requires you to return a non-nullable Long. Your code returns a nullable long.

Comment: Just add `?: super.getItemId(position)` or make your `myList` non nullable.  This does solve duplication for similar views in a recyclerview with unique data.

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling except for reusing it for the same item, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
     return position
}
```

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling except for reusing it for the same item, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

use holder.setIsRecyclable(false); in onBindViewHolder of your adapter class

Comment: Well I don't think set recycling to false is good idea but I tried everything and this is the only solution that worked for me

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

This question may be old but some information is not revealed.
I faced a similar issue and stumbled on this question. After doing research for many weeks, I realized that overriding

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

and

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

did not help me(It may help another person tho).

The issue was that the views were recycled. But that is not an issue because that is the main essence of recyclerview. So, here is the fix

```
override fun onViewRecycled(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewRecycled(holder)

    holder.title.setText(null)
}
```

When views are recycled, its viewholder still has the previous value of where it was used. If `(items.get(position).getTitle()` returns a value, it resets the text value of title correctly, else if it returns null, it retains the value from the recycled view. So, the example I just showed you resets the text value of the title to `null` whenever a view is recycled.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **RecyclerView** and your adapter extends **PagedListAdapter** or **ListAdapter**, then use this way to prevent duplication of the items when you click on them.

```
int position = getAdapterPosition();
Movie movie = getCurrentList().get(position);
```

It is my case, but change the object according to your project.
This solution works, take a look [here](https://github.com/Marwa-Eltayeb/MovieTrailer/blob/f8f72cd396ec94205c4cd5dde104bdced7a02683/app/src/main/java/com/marwaeltayeb/movietrailer/adapters/MovieAdapter.java#L81)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Sujit Yadav is good for JAVA

Here is the solution in Kotlin

```
    class MyAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {
    
        init {
            setHasStableIds(true)
        }

       override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
       }
    
        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            return position
        }
    
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }
    
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

it helped me

Comment: **I would strongly advise against this solution** and the many similar ones in the other answers (note: I am the maintainer of RecyclerView). This works by completely disabling recycling except for reusing it for the same item, thus negating most of the benefits of RecyclerView.    If this is happening, there is a bug in your code somewhere, either in the adapter code itself ([as is the case in the question's code](//stackoverflow.com/a/32771573/208273)) or in how you're notifying it of dataset changes.  You should fix it properly, rather than causing collateral damage with this solution.