# RecyclerView gets overlap in calling notifyItemInserted and notifyItemRangeChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have my RecyclerView with a dynamic content such as add and deleting before it was okay but one day it becomes buggy and weird like this.

[image]

Using notifyItemInserted() followed by notifyItemRangeChanged() to update the list is working fine last month. I also tried to update my dependencies to 28.0.0 and not work. This is just a Activity with a RecyclerView. Still I cannot figure it out because back then this is not happening.

Here is my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDarker"
tools:context=".common.AnnouncementComments"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/commentLinear"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titleBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/comment_section"
            android:textColor="@color/icon_selected"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView
            android:id="@+id/comment_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">

            <com.bitwise.rotaractclubapp.system.AutoPlayVideoRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/commentRecycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />

            </com.yalantis.phoenix.PullToRefreshView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noComments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/be_the_first_in_this_comment_section"
            android:textColor="@color/not_selected"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/commentLinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <com.sackcentury.shinebuttonlib.ShineButton
            android:id="@+id/videoBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/help"
            app:allow_random_color="true"
            app:big_shine_color="@color/highlighted"
            app:click_animation_duration="350"
            app:enable_flashing="true"
            app:shine_animation_duration="5000"
            app:shine_count="15"
            app:shine_turn_angle="20"
            app:siShape="@drawable/ic_movie_creation_black_24dp"
            app:small_shine_offset_angle="40"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_movie_creation_black_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/highlighted" />


        <com.sackcentury.shinebuttonlib.ShineButton
            android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/help"
            app:allow_random_color="true"
            app:big_shine_color="@color/highlighted"
            app:click_animation_duration="350"
            app:enable_flashing="true"
            app:shine_animation_duration="5000"
            app:shine_count="15"
            app:shine_turn_angle="20"
            app:siShape="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
            app:small_shine_offset_angle="40"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_black_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/highlighted" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/your_comment"
            android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/icon_selected"
            android:textColorHint="@color/icon_not_selected"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop"
            tools:ignore="Autofill" />

        <com.sackcentury.shinebuttonlib.ShineButton
            android:id="@+id/sendingBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:contentDescription="@string/help"
            app:allow_random_color="true"
            app:big_shine_color="@color/highlighted"
            app:click_animation_duration="350"
            app:enable_flashing="true"
            app:shine_animation_duration="5000"
            app:shine_count="15"
            app:shine_turn_angle="20"
            app:siShape="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
            app:small_shine_offset_angle="40"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
            app:tint="@color/highlighted" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/filesRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please share adapter code and recycler view item xml

Comment: this may helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32771302/recyclerview-items-duplicate-and-constantly-changing

Comment: My issue is with overlapping not just duplicate item.

Comment: share adapter code as well as item xml file

Comment: the code is too long to be included please refer to this https://drive.google.com/open?id=1mfhPZKZ4lBzcIdM3DHRi0nbI-cXt6cLq

Comment: do u have teamViewer ? connect with me your code was too long

Comment: I do not have teamViewer

Comment: You should not use `Handler.post` to bind your views in `onBindViewHolder`, that is because it will bind the views asynchronously and after `notifyItemInserted` or `notifyItemRangeChanged` is called, which explains the unexpected layout behaviour.

Comment: That doesn't fix the issue and definitely not because I use to this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue it was a silly mistake and took me weeks trying to figure out.
The cause of the problem is declaring some item to be non-recyclable `setIsRecyclable(false)`.